# Django: Why I can't access extra fields in Many to Many relationship with _set.all in templates. What is wrong?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to print the extra field `is_valid` of Class `GroupMember` (ManytoMany relation with Class `Group`). In templates I do:

```
{% for field in user.groupmember_set.all %}{{ field.is_valid }}<br>{% endfor %}
```

But nothing is shown. Where is the problem?
The relevant code is below

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="GroupMember")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_groups',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="memberships",on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("group", "user")
```

`views.py`

```
class SingleGroup(DetailView):
    model = Group
```

`urls.py`

```
path("groups/<pk>/",views.SingleGroup.as_view(),name="single"),
```

`template: groups/<pk>`

```
{% for field in user.groupmember_set.all %}{{ field.is_valid }}<br>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you applied related_name="memberships". now this: user.memberships

Comment: can you elaborate more? `user.memberships_set.all` doesn't work. I'm interested in the field `is_valid`

Comment: special property (object) with the name secondary model_set is created in the primary model by default. In your case, for example: groupmember_set. But since you've changed the name, it's now memberships, without the _set prefix. Here you can [read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.default_related_name)  See section: default_related_name. This property is created in lowercase.

Comment: did you try to apply like this: user.memberships.all?

Comment: yes. it doesn't work. what may be wrong?

Comment: However what fixes the problem is removing the `related_name=memberships`. then it works with `projectmember_set.all`. But for it to work I need to do makemigrations and migrate. So the questions remains, why `user.memberships.all` won't work

Comment: see answer below.

Comment: You've set `related_name='user_groups'` that means that you have to write `user.user_groups.all` if the object in your template is a `User` object named `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Addressed through the Group object to the GroupMember records. Do you need it?
**Replace bboard with the name of the folder where your templates are placed.**
I have this: templates/bboard which are in the application folder.

views.py

```
class SingleGroup(DetailView):
    model = Group
    template_name = 'bboard/templ.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context)
        return context
```

templ.html

```
{% for aaa in group.memberships.all %}
<p>{{ aaa }}</p>
<p>{{ aaa.group }}</p>
<p>{{ aaa.is_valid }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<p>{{ 'group.name:' }} {{ group.name }}</p>
```